# Kivy. Приложение из двух страниц PageLayout

Tags: python, kivy

Как на kivy реализовать приложение из двух страниц. Так что бы при нажатии на кнопку на первой странице появлялать вторая, и наоборот. И данные передавались из первой страницы во вторую.
Пытаюсь сделать через PageLayout. Не выходит..

```
# Custom button
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

<TrafGridLayout>:
    id: traffictax
    display_distance: distance
    display_cost: cost
    rows: 13
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10

    PageLayout:
        border: 10

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Форма заявки'

            Label:
                text: 'Введите города'

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Откуда'
                TextInput:
                    id: point_from
                    font_size: 14
                    multiline: False
                    text: ''

            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: 'Куда'
                TextInput:
                    id: point_to
                    font_size: 14
                    multiline: False
                    text: ''

            # При нажатии на кнопку "Рассчитать" данные передаются в функцию "calculate" и происходит переключение на вторую страницу
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 10
                CustButton:
                    text: "Рассчитать"
                    on_press:
                        traffictax.calculate(point_from.text, point_to.text)
                        traffictax.show_page(1)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Результат'

            Label:
                text: 'Длина маршрута'

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    id: distance
                    font_size: 14
                    multiline: False

            Label:
                text: 'Стоимость'

            BoxLayout:
                TextInput:
                    id: cost
                    font_size: 14
                    multiline: False

            # При нажатии на кнопку "Назад" происходит переключение на первую страницу
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 10
                CustButton:
                    text: "Назад к форме расчёта"
                    on_press: traffictax.show_page(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить ScreenManager и два элемента Screen, а в них уже пихайте лэйауты, переход между ними при помощи root.manager.current = 'needed layout screen'

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло